# Can Crawler4j interpret wildcarding using astericks(*) in robots.txt?

Tags: wildcard, robots.txt, crawler4j

I want to be able to block web-crawlers from accessing pages other than ***page1***.

The following should be able to block all directories/file names containing the word ***page***.  So something like /localhost/myApp/page2.xhtml should be blocked.

```
#Disallow: /*page
```

The following should enable all directories/file names containing ***page1*** to be accessible.  So something like /localhost/myApp/page1.xhtml should not be blocked.

```
#Allow: /*page1
```

The problem is crawler4j seems to ignoring the astericks which is used for wildcards.  Is something wrong with my robots.txt or is the astericks something crawler4j does not interpret by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the crawler4j [source code](https://github.com/MadEgg/crawler4j/tree/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/robotstxt), and it looks like crawler4j does not support wildcards in Allow or Disallow, except in the special case where the asterisk is the last character in the directive. (and then the asterisk is ignored anyway)